# OneToMany deleteById method in JPA repository is not working

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have entities and store them in h2 database. All unnecessary fields are omited.

```java
@Data
@Table
@Entity
public class Section {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "section", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Subsection> subsections = new HashSet<>();
}

@Repository
public interface SectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Section, Long> {}

@Data
@Table
@Entity
public class Subsection {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
  private Section section;
}

@Repository
public interface SubsectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Subsection, Long> {}
```

Firstly I save one `Section` and one `Subsection`. Result in h2-console:
[image]
Then I want to delete `Subsection` from `Section`. Method example:

```java
public void deleteById(Long id) {
  subsectionRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

As a result nothing is deleted. I tried to add `orphanRemoval = true` but no effect.
I also tried to remove parent from child and save `Subsection` again without parent and then call `deleteById(id)` method and as a result row was not deleted but value in `SECTION_ID` was `null`. Also tried following settings in `Subsection`.

```java
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
  private Section section;
```

But as it was expected child was deleted with parent.
Do I use some annotations incorrectly or I forgot to add something? What is the reason that child can't be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I want to delete Subsection from Section. Method example:
>
> public void deleteById(Long id) {
> subsectionRepository.deleteById(id); }

What you want to do, would not be done the way you try it. As you have configured it it would be

```
Subsenction subsenction1 = subsectionRepository.findById(id); 
section.getSubSenctions().remove(subsenction1);
```

Then it will be dereferenced from Table Senction. After that because of orphan removal it would be also removed from table Subsenction

Another pitfall that is very common is `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods **that are not based on the ID field** on JPA objects or are the default ones which from JVM are not based on ID field anyways.

Comment: yes, I can delete child after removing child from parent